# How to wait for new input from file InputStream

Tags: streams, import

I'm trying to open a file to read and do some processing indefinitely until I decide to abort:

```
MyInputStream = OpenRead["data.csv"]
While[True, 
  rec = Read[MyInputStream, Record];
  MyProcessing[rec]
]
```

or, say:

```
Dynamic[MyProcessing[Read[MyInputStream, Record]]]
```

In other words, I want any of `Read`, `ReadString`, `ReadList` to be *blocking* and wait for input. Currently, it stops on `EndOfFile` even though the file I opened keeps growing.
I cannot do anything to make it blocking with what the official documentation provides.

I also found that if I stream my data through a socket rather than a file, I am able to achieve what I want to do using *`SocketListen`* (the documentation has an explicit answer), but I want to stick to simple file I/O for now. Here is how to solve the problem if I send my data over local socket on port 5555:

```
SocketListen[SocketOpen[5555], (Data = #Data) &];
Dynamic[MyProcessing[Data]]
```

I would also like to *avoid polling* solutions.

Can someone help, please?

Comment: `ReadString` is actually blocking. I believe that the problem is that file you are trying to read is already complete. There is no reason for `ReadString` to wait for input because there is no indication that the file is going to change. Once the file is read, you get an EOF marker.

Comment: Okay, thanks, so it is a question about file I/O not `ReadString`? @Szabolcs

Comment: My file is updated in a shell script like `cmd >> data.csv`. `cmd` itself is a never-ending process. I suppose I should go somewhere else with a question about shell scripting, then?

Comment: I did not say anything about the question being off topic. I am not sure why you interpreted it that way. My point was that if you insist on using a file, polling is likely unavoidable. Try not to use a file. Read directly form the output of `cmd` (e.g. with `RunProcess`, see all the `ReadString` examples, or just open `"!cmd"` as if it were a file. If this is not possible, e.g. because `cmd` was already running before you started Mathematica, then use `tail -f` as an intermediary.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you. I found the solution using `StartProcess` and `tail -f`. I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: No, I was genuinely interested if my problem should be solved with file I/O manipulations before I feed the file to Mathematica code. Maybe my script can write into a file in some way that makes the file not "complete" as you described, which then makes the question probably OS specific, I don't know. I'm sorry my formulation confused you. @Szabolcs

Comment: Have you seen [`StreamPosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPosition.html) and [`SetStreamPosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetStreamPosition.html)?

Comment: @BenIzd, yes, I didn't find it useful in my case. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 3):

If your system has `tail` or alternatives:

```
TailProcess = StartProcess[{"tail", "-f", "data.csv"}];
```

and use `Read`/`ReadLine`/... on `TailProcess`.
Credits to @Szabolcs.

For now, it is an appealing solution to me, although it makes me dependent on one additional link in the processing chain.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

To demonstrate, there is a python script that adds a new line of text every `1.5` seconds, 4 times, and a `counter` variable to run the loop only 12 times.

First, we create a stream with `OpenRead`, and by using `SetStreamPosition`, it'll set to zero first. After reading, `lastPosition` will be updated, the `stream` will be closed, the stream position will be checked, if it doesn't change (`lastPosition == newPosition`) then we'll wait `1.5` seconds otherwise the content will be printed and ...

> If your case involves removing data, this code may return an error because in `SetStreamPosition` it may exceed the file limits. The code only covers appending new data.

```
Block[{counter = 0, newPosition = 0, lastPosition = 0, content, stream},
 While[True,
  If[counter > 12, Break[]];
  stream = OpenRead["D:\\test.txt"];
  SetStreamPosition[stream, lastPosition];
  content = Read[stream, String];
  newPosition = StreamPosition[stream];
  Close[stream];
  If[lastPosition != newPosition, Print[content], Pause[1.5]];
  lastPosition = newPosition;
  counter += 1;
  ]
 ]
```